# JQuery Swap 2 div's z-index

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, z-index, swap

I tried to swap the z-index of two `div` elements.

The following code is my attempt to switch the two z-indices:

```
else if (pen_state == 1) {
                var pen_zindex = $("#pen").css("z-index");
                var curtain_zindex = $("#curtain").css("z-index");
                if (curtain_zindex < pen_zindex) {
                    $("#curtain").css('z-index',pen_zindex);
                    $("#pen").css('z-index',curtain_zindex);
                }
            }
```

But whatever I do, I can not swap them.

Comment: Can you post your HTML and CSS as well? z-index works on some specific "position" only, i.e. position: relative or position: absolute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have seems to work for me when the elements are `position:absolute`.  See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/ChrisMBarr/AZXmU/